# Como pegar primeiro valor retornado pelo foreach

Tags: php, if, foreach, empty

Pessoal sou novo em programação e estou tentando resolver meu problema com foreach...

Tenho um foreach que me retorna os grupos de fotos que possuem fotos neles... porém eu preciso pegar o primeiro grupo que o foreach encontrar fotos e aplicar o atributo checked na tag input dele... Eu tentei fazer com empty porém não estou conseguindo... Segue abaixo o código... Obrigado! Abraço!

```
@foreach($property_get->getPhotoGroupList() as $key => $grupo)
  <input id="tab{{ $key }}" type="radio" name="tabs" {{  !empty($key) ? 'checked'  :  ' ' }}>
  <label class="band band-two lastWord" for="tab{{ $key }}">{{ $grupo->getName() }}</label>@endforeach
```

Comment: Da um print_r($property_get->getPhotoGroupList()) e posta aqui o resultado

Comment: Ele aparece um array aqui

array:4 [▼
  3 => PhotoGroup {#391 ▶}
  1 => PhotoGroup {#394 ▶}
  2 => PhotoGroup {#406 ▶}
  4 => PhotoGroup {#409 ▶}
]

Answer (score 1):

veirifica se a chave é a primeira chave se sim marca checked caso contrario não marca

```
@foreach($property_get->getPhotoGroupList() as $key => $grupo)
    <input id="tab{{ $key }}" type="radio" name="tabs" {{  @if($key == 0) ? 'checked'  :  ' ' }}>
    <label class="band band-two lastWord" for="tab{{ $key }}">{{ $grupo->getName() }}</label>
@endforeach
```

Comment: Ele está dando erro de sintaxe... provavelmente porque está sendo feito em laravel né ?

Comment: Tente adicionar um @ antes do if   exemplo  @if($key == 0)

Comment: ou  remover o  {{ }}, nunca  usei  o  frameword do laravel com Blade